# Writing a Prolog program that is supposed to multiply every element in the list by a number

Tags: list, prolog, multiplication

I am trying to write a Prolog code that takes two input arguments, and one output argument.  The predicate will be given a list and a number and find a list whose elements are equivalent to the original list with each element multiplied by the given number.

for example:

```
multiply_list([1, 2, 3, 4, 5] , 3, Result).
Result = [3, 6, 9, 12, 15]
```

I wrote this and I get a "out of global stack" error.

```
multiply_list([], _, 0).
multiply_list([X|Xs], Number, Result):-
    X1 = X * Number,
    append(Result, X1, Result),
    multiply_list(Xs, Number, Result).
```

Can someone help me figure out why it is throwing this error? Thanks!

Alright so I no longer get the "out of global stack" error but, it still is not correct.  Can you point me where my code is wrong? thanks

```
multiply_list([], _, []).
multiply_list([X|Xs], Number, Result):-
     X1 is X * Number,
     Result is [X1|NewXs],
     multiply_list(Xs, Number, NewXs).
```

Comment: Use `is/2` for arithmetic expression unification with a variable, not the `=/2` unification operator, which will not evaluate expressions. Also, your recursion means you do not need `append/3`. The append is causing the infinite execution, blowing the stack (if you do a `trace` you'll see the details). `Result` is `[X1|NewXs]` where `multiply_list(Xs, Number, NewXs)`. And your base case should be `multiply_list([], _, [])` since the last argument is a *list* not a *number*;

Comment: Thank you for the help! I am a little confused on the "NewXs". What are these representing?

multiply_list([], _, []).

multiply_list([X|Xs], Number, Result):-
 X1 is X * Number,
 Result is [X1|NewXs],
 multiply_list(Xs, Number, NewXs).

Is this what you meant?

Comment: multiply_list([], _, []).

multiply_list([X|Xs], Number, Result):-
 X1 is X * Number,
 Result is [X1|NewXs],
 multiply_list(Xs, Number, NewXs).

Comment: `NewXs` is the list you get when you multiply all the elements in `Xs` by `Number`. You can call it whatever you wish.

Comment: In prolog, these are predicates. So they define what a multiplied list should look like. `multiply_list([], _, [])` says that *an empty list multiplied by anything is an empty list*. `multiply_list([X|Xs], Number, Result) :- ...` should say, *`Result` is the result of multiplying every number in `[X|Xs]` by `Number` if...<something>*. In this case, the *something* is that `Result` has a first element of `X1` where `X1 is X * Number`, and then the *tail* of `Result` should be the result of multiplying the list `Xs` by `Number`, which is what `multiply_list` does.

Comment: This time you have it the other way around. `[X1|NewXs]` is *not* an arithmetic expression, so you cannot use `is/2` to *evaluate* it. You want to *unify* `Result` with `[X1|NewXs]`, which is done with `Result = [X1|NewXs]`. `=/2` is for unifying. `is/2` is for *evaluating an arithmetic expression* (2nd argument), which I mentioned in my first comment, then unifying that result with the first argument.

Comment: *Still is not correct* is a poorly worded result of your test. I'm sure it's giving you an expression error for the `is/2` which is what should have been stated. But it's because of using `is/2` inappropriately instead of using `=/2`.

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your help.  It now works!

Comment: There are a couple of principles here you should come to an understanding of as a result of this exercise. One is the Prolog pattern of recursively processing a list. The second is the difference between using `is/2` and `=/2`.